# Search Google Cloud Storage PHP Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, google-cloud-storage

I am not a programmer so I use Laravel and a Cloud Storage Client for PHP.

```
https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php-storage
```

So far I can list a folder in a bucket.

```
$disk = Storage::disk('gcs');
$gcsMedia = $disk->listContents('my-folder');
// Create a new Laravel collection from the array data
$itemCollection = collect($gcsMedia);
```

Can anyone tell me in understandable language for n00bs how to search files by a keyword?

Comment: You want to search the file contents or file names?

Comment: Could you also specify where do you want to perform the search? are you looking for a integrated method on the CS lib that retrieves files according to a keyword ? because that's not available, you can retrieve files based on a prefix though -> https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/listing-objects

Comment: @Mayeru thanks for the reply, I decided to retrieve all files and filter it with laravel